# Jquery Select Change Event - Lose Focus

Tags: jquery, select

I am creating floating labels for my `select` elements when a user selects an option.

```
<div class="jvFloat"><label class="placeHolder active" for="input_18_61">Salutation</label><select name="input_61" class="gfield_select newsel" tabindex="49" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"><option value="" selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">Salutation</option><option value="Miss">Miss</option><option value="Ms.">Ms.</option><option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option></select>
```

However the floating label, only appears when the user selects another input or loses focus of the `select` element.

How could I use the Jquery `select change` event, to de-focus the `select` element, after the user makes a choice?

```
$('select').change(function(){

})
.change();
```

Comment: Not sure about that.. I have some other code inside the code I specified, and the 'change' event fires when the option is changed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work..

```
$('select').change(function(){

    $(this).trigger('blur');

})
```